# Type casting a Number to double

Tags: java, android, casting

I am trying to compute few calculations for my project and I get following `java.lang.ClassCastException` for 

`y2= (double) molWt[x];`

`molWt` and `dist` are two array of type Number and  `double` respectively.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Double

```
public Double calcData(Number[] molWt, Double[] dist, String unk) {
        Double y2,y1, newY = null;
        Double x1,x2;

        Double unkn = Double.parseDouble(unk.toString());
        Double prev=0d;
        Double slope;


        for (int x = 0; x < dist.length; x++)
            if (unkn > prev && unkn < dist[x]) {
                y2 = (double) molWt[x];
                y1 = (double) molWt[x - 1];

                x2 = dist[x];
                x1 = dist[x - 1];

                slope = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));

                newY = slope * (unkn - x1) + y1;


            } else {
                prev = dist[x];
            }

        return newY;
    }
```

Comment: Well clearly `molWt` has at least one `Integer` in it. Is that a surprise? What is your actual question?

Comment: I can't see why you are using `Number` at all. Both arrays should be `double[]`. In my opinion, `Number` is completely useless.

Comment: Followup to comment by @PaulBoddington, why are you using boxed `Double` instead of primitive `double`? Can they be `null`? If so, your code will die a horrible death.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [Number.doubleValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue%28%29):

```
y2 = molWt[x].doubleValue();
```

instead of trying to cast. `Number` cannot be cast to a primitive `double`.

Comment: You beat me to it by a second - hope you don't mind me adding the link!

Comment: may throw runtime exception

Answer (score 2):

you can use java.lang.Number.doubleValue() method to cast a number to a double object.

y2=  molWt[x].doubleValue()

Comment: There's no point in posting an answer which merely duplicates another.